# How to turn plain text into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm extracting a list of common queries via an API for Google Trends:

```
!pip install pytrends
import pandas as pd                        
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrend = TrendReq()
ytrend.build_payload(kw_list=['urban dictionary'],timeframe='2019-01-01 2019-12-31')
related_queries = pytrend.related_queries()
related_queries.values()
```

My issue is that `related_queries.values()` is a dictionary with one single value, which is plain text:

```
    dict_values([{'top':                       query  value
0      the urban dictionary    100
1                definition     50
2    urban dictionary words     12
3    urban dictionary names     10
4     word urban dictionary     10
5          urban outfitters      9
6     thot urban dictionary      8
7      dog urban dictionary      6
8      cap urban dictionary      6
9     urban dictionary yeet      6
10                     yeet      6
11     top urban dictionary      5
12    stan urban dictionary      4
13  urban dictionary boomer      4
14                   boomer      4
15    fomo urban dictionary      4
16    urban dictionary drip      4
17     smh urban dictionary      4
18                      smh      4
19                urban air      3
20     tea urban dictionary      3
21   green urban dictionary      3
22     bet urban dictionary      3
23                     vsco      3
24    goat urban dictionary      3
```

I want to convert that dictionary into a data frame with three columns - index, query and popularity. Any idea how to do that?

Cheers,

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 1):

You dictionary `related_queries` has a key called `urban dictionary` which contains two additional dictionaries `top` and `rising`, I would iterate through these last two keys and create a dictionary of dataframes:

```
dataframes = dict()

for key, value in related_queries['urban dictionary'].items():
    dataframes[key] = pd.DataFrame(value)

dataframes['top'].head(4)

#    query                  value
# 0  the urban dictionary   100
# 1  definition             51
# 2  urban dictionary words 13
# 3  word urban dictionary  11
```